# WCF can't serialize cyclic references

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, silverlight-4.0

I have a database with a lots of relationships between `Tables` and a `Silverlight` client that connects to my server with `WCF service` on `ASP.Net` side.

First i used `LINQ to SQL` as a robust mapper tables to object and in a `WebMethod` that returns a `List<Foo>` of my Database's object(suppose `GetFoo()`). The `Foo` has lots of relationships with other objects that each of that have lots of realaships too,(this means , there is a PK and FK between tables).also i use `Microsoft Service Trace Viewr` for track my service

When i call GetFoo() , WCF returns this error:

> Object graph for type 'X.Y.Z' contains  cycles and cannot be serialized if
>   reference tracking is disabled

I searched this error and find [this great post](http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/02/wcf-cyclic-references-support.html) but that is not working properly and i see same error too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various options:

- remove the cyclic dependencies from your model; this *might* be tricky for a generated model that has lots of existing code built against it, but is worth a *try*; however, you *typically* want to not serialize the *parent*, which is exactly what LINQ-to-SQL **wants** you to keep (it'll let you drop the *children* property, but that is what you usually want to serialize)
- enable cyclic references; it looks like you've tried this without success; did you enable it *at both ends*, though? Actually I wouldn't be surprised if Silverlight doesn't like this extension (it has limited extension support)
- use a separate (flat) DTO model for data transfer purposes
- try using NetDataContractSerializer; I can't remember if this is supported in Silverlight, and I must admit I'm not its biggest fan, but it might be a pragmatic fix here

I'd vote firmly in the "DTO model" category; simply, having a separate model means you are less likely to run into tangles whenever you tweak the DB - and you are in complete control over it.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: i can't remove cyclic dependencies , it's lot! have any code to detect it? if i want to use DTO i must create and implement more than 200 object and i have deadline!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: enable cyclic references? how to do in ends?

Comment: @Meysam - like in the blog article you linked to; but it needs to apply at both the client and server. I haven't tried that in silverlight, so I can't comment on whether it is possible.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: and how to find cyclic dependencies automatically? is there any way?

Comment: @Meysam - well, you could write something with reflection fairly easily that simply walks the properties

Answer (score 2):

A bit late this. But if anyone are using linqtosql and have this problem you can simply just open the tables in your dbml class. Right click next to a table and click properties.
HEre there is a property named Serialization Mode.. Set it to Unidirectional

The error will be gone

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question now, but did you try decorating the classes generated by your DBML with [DataContract(IsReference=True)]?

I had the same problem in 2010 and had to resort to some fairly extreme measures to get it to work on client and service sides, but recently went back through it with VS2013/.NET 4.5 and had much less pain, as documented here (with EF v6 RC 1 POCO objects): http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/more-with-the-entity-framework-v6-rc1/12423/