# Entity Framework : get related entities

Tags: frameworks, entity, entities

I created a WCF service with Entity Framework.

I have 2 tables : Theaters and Locality. Locality as a foreign key in Theaters.

My method :

```
public theater[] GetTheaters()
{

    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        return context.theater.ToArray();

    }
}
```

I have to remove the "virtual" keyword from "public virtual locality locality { get; set; }" in my theater class. Otherwise, I get a CommunicationException.

But when I do that, I get my list of theaters but the locality is null...

How can I get the locality ?

Thanks

My model class ( I also have other entities) :

```
    public partial class locality
    {
        public locality()
        {
            this.theater = new HashSet<theater>();
        }

        public int idLocality { get; set; }
        public int npa { get; set; }
        public string locality1 { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<theater> theater { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class theater
    {
        public theater()
        {
            this.session = new HashSet<session>();
        }

        public int idTheater { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int idLocality { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public int seats { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public bool threeD { get; set; }

        public  locality locality { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<session> session { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the error that I get :

"Object graph for type 'locality' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.

EDIT :

The solution that I found :

In my locality class, I had a Collection of theaters.

I had to add "private to the setter like this :

"   public  ICollection theater { get; private set; }"

So it works, but I still have a problem, I can't access to the theaters from the locality entity anymore. (no more bi-directional)

Comment: Post more code for your model classes. You might have something wrong in that part

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force related entities to load, you can use the [Include method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) to do so. By default, related entities are loaded Lazily.

Your example would be:

```
public theater[] GetTheaters()
{

    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        return context.theater.Include(t=>t.Locality).ToArray();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eager loading or explicit loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx). With eager loading you use the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) extension method:

```
return context.Theater.Include(t => t.Locality).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this but I get a CommunicationException... Do I need to set "LazyLoading Enabled" to False in the properties of my edmx model ? And keep the "virtual" keyword  from "public virtual locality locality { get; set; }" in my theater class ?

Comment: Yes, you should still disable lazy loading when working with types that need to be serialized. The virtual keyword on navigation properties is one of the requirements of lazy loading, so removing it disables it, but you should explicitly switch it off (or proxy creation completely).

Comment: Here is my error with the Test Client (sorry, part in french... ) : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9197067/commerror.png

Comment: That looks like a separate issue, is the service running and exposed at that endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner and didn't fully understand your question, but it works if I try to only load the theaters without locality. So it should'nt be a problem with the service...

Comment: Does the Locality type have any navigation properties marked with virtual? Have you disabled lazy loading or proxy creation explicitly? Are your WCF proxy types up to date with the service?

Comment: I removed all the "virtual" from my classes, disabled lazy loading in my Model.edmx properties and in my method (  context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; ) and yes. 

Here is another screenshot to see the problem. The getTheaters works (with locality = null) but the getMovies doesn't work (with the Include) :  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9197067/wcf.png

Comment: You've disabled lazy loading in GetTheaters, but you're not eagerly loading the localities. If you still get an exception, can you get to the inner exception details?

Comment: It was to show that it wored without loading the localities, but I still get the error... I get this error : "Object graph for type 'locality' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled."

Comment: You could either try and remove any cyclic dependencies on the Locality type, or move away from passing your EF DTOs around with WCF, and use specific WCF DTO types that a separate from your data access layer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012289/wcf-cant-serialize-cyclic-references

Comment: OK I found the solution. Thank you very much for your help. I Will Edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the correct annotations to create the relationships. See the code below. (or create the relationships yourself if using the FluentAPI)

Look for the `[Key]` and `[ForeignKey]` annotations, as well as the `virtual` keyword.

```
public partial class locality
    {
        public locality()
        {
            //this.theater = new HashSet<theater>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int idLocality { get; set; }

        public int npa { get; set; }
        public string locality1 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<theater> theaters { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class theater
    {
        public theater()
        {
            //this.session = new HashSet<session>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int idTheater { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public int idLocality { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public int seats { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public bool threeD { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("idLocality")]
        public virtual locality locality { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<session> session { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I found another solution but I will look at this if I still have problems

Comment: You can post your other solution as an answer and select it as the solution

Comment: I am new here so I can't add an answer for 8 hours after asking :)